# Weird black shadows in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, artifacts

There are weird shadows on my model in cycles and I have no idea why.

What is this and how to fix this? Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You likely need more transmission bounces.

Comment: more transmission bounces didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try transparency bounces.

Comment: @SergeL , thanks so much man!, I've managed to fix my problem thanks to your help:)